# Synonym of itself - "user-defined-functions"

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I was looking at the `suggested` tab of the tag synonyms page to see if I needed to vote on anything, and noticed a synonym that the system says I created for [user-defined-functions](/questions/tagged/user-defined-functions), but it was a synonym to itself.

[image]

I remember dealing with the category and creating synonyms for it, but would never have made a synonym to itself.  I figure there had been retagging going on that made it end up that way.  I'd appreciated it if someone could delete that suggested tag synonym.

[image: UDF Tag Synonym header]

[image: UDF proposed tag synonyms]

Comment: It is probable that you suggested a synonym for a tag that has been then merged with [tag:user-defined-functions]. I don't see any harm on that synonym suggestion; as long as it is not up-voted, it will never be created, and probably it will never be created even if it gets the necessary votes.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is, do we really need `user-defined-functions` as a tag?  I'd say no, since most code that we write is "A function provided by the user of a program or an environment" (as per the tag wiki).  I don't see how you can't write a program *without* a user-defined function, going by the definition here (pretty much *every* question on Stack Overflow should be tagged with this then).

Comment: @casperOne, there are many places that udfs are used that have separate meanings and implementations that normal coding, Excel is a great example.  UDFs there have to be handled differently than normal VBA code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, yes, it could stay there forever, but why not just clean it up?

Comment: @LanceRoberts I don't disagree, but your point just points out that the tag is ambiguous, at best, and shouldn't exist.  Ambiguous tags don't serve SO well.

Comment: Have you never heard of a user-defined-function for a user-defined-function? It's an inception tag ;)

Comment: Note to closers: The reason used 'This question is only applicable to one specific site on the Stack Exchange network' is invalid because this question was created before this was broken off from Stack Overflow. If the problem has been solved, then tag it as 'status-completed'.

Comment: @LanceRoberts it was a valid question before the split indeed. But it no longer is. We don't want to set the precedent that we accept these kind of questions. I don't know who stumbled across your post and cast the first close vote, but I agree that these pre-split post should be closed, but I wouldn't go actively looking for them.